# Button showing h1, then showing another h1 if clicked again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a button, when I click it for the first time it shows for example an Ad, when clicked again it doesn't show the ad but the content. Here is what I tried:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const ad = document.querySelector('.ad');
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt');

let ads = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ads = true
      ad.style.display = 'block'

      if (ads) {
        ad.style.display = 'none';
        cnt.style.display = 'block';
      })
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
  <h1 style="display: none" class="ad">Ad</h1>
  <h1 style="display: none" class="cnt">Content</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(ads)` - of course that condition is _always_ true - because you set `ads = true` three lines before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const ad = document.querySelector('.ad');
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt');

let ads = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ad.style.display = 'block'
    
        if(ads) {
        ad.style.display = 'none';
        cnt.style.display = 'block';
        }
        ads = true // new location
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
        <h1 style="display: none" class="ad">Ad</h1>
        <h1 style="display: none" class="cnt">Content</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Since you set `ads` to true before checking if the variable is true, the variable is true at the first click.

set it at the bottom like this

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ad.style.display = 'block'
    
        if(ads) {
        ad.style.display = 'none';
        cnt.style.display = 'block';
        }
        ads = true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ads = true` with `ads = !ads` to **toggle** it.

Currently your `ads` is always `true`, leading to your `if (ads) { ... }` block being executed every time.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const ad = document.querySelector('.ad');
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt');

let ads = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ads = !ads
  ad.style.display = 'block'

  if (ads) {
    ad.style.display = 'none';
    cnt.style.display = 'block';
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
  <h1 style="display: none" class="ad">Ad</h1>
  <h1 style="display: none" class="cnt">Content</h1>
</div>
```